# Docker run in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a command that I am currently running from my OS to run a docker container that takes in a file as an argument and returns some output.

`docker run --rm -v ${pwd}:/dir IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARGS]`

This allows me to run this container each time i get a new file, obtain output, and spin down the container. I would like to move this to AWS but I'm a bit unsure of how I'd be able to replicate the ad-hoc nature of this command? Does AWS Support `docker run`?

Comment: The docker run command will of cause work on AWS too. The problem with migrating to AWS is there are multiple options supporting different requirements. You already mentioned AWS ECS which is intended for running docker containers, but  it assumes the image and parameters are more or less fixed. If not, there are other ways to run a container with dynamic parameters (on EC2, as an AWS Batch job,...)

Comment: ECS is a remote cloud environment, and there's no direct way to launch an ECS container mounting your local filesystem like the `docker run -v` option.  If you want to use ECS here, you'll need to restructure your application to accept its input in some other way (an HTTP POST, a file in S3, an SQS message, ...).

Answer (score 0):

So, the short answer is no, you do not have the ability to do this on ECS like how you do normally. However, you can build it so you spin up tasks dynamically when a file is uploaded in say S3.

What you want to do is:

S3 Event Notification => EventBridge => StepFunction => ECS RunTask API

With a setup like this, you will be able to run a task to process a file each time it's uploaded
useful links:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-amazon-eventbridge-service-integration-for-aws-step-functions/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html

Comment: EventBridge can run the ECS task directly. StepFunctions isn't needed here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ecs-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a gazillion ways you can refactor your application to run on AWS as others have described. If you do not want to go down that path perhaps the closest architecture to what you are already doing on your laptop would be to use AWS ECS + the EFS integration (as described in [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/)). You can define a task (with a container) that mounts an EFS share. By populating that EFS share with the file you need will have the container access that file and work on it just like it does locally on your laptop.